# Is it possible for a host to lock a php ini settings?

Tags: php, web-hosting, php-ini

I'm working on a website which requires the use of sessions. However the default value for the life of a session is 1440 seconds or 24 mins. I have tried to change this using `ini_set()` making sure to put the `ini_set()` before the `session_start()` and then checking it with `ini_get()`. The `ini_get()` returns the value I have set but the session still seems to follow the default rules set.

So is it possible for a host to lock out editing of the ini settings?

Comment: I believe i'm using linux with apache.

Comment: yes. A host can force any settings they want or disable you from making changes if they want. Especially with something with external files like sessions where they could be doing their own garbage collection.

Comment: Which ini value are you actually changing? You'd normally set cookie parameters with `session_set_cookie_params()` - the ini var `session_gc_maxlifetime` has no effect on the lifetime of the cookie - merely the amount of time before garbage collection **might** run.

Comment: Sorry I did use session_set_cookie_params() also but this didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: possibly.

It could be that they've disabled use of `ini_set` via the `disable_functions` directive in the global php.ini, however that doesn't explain the behavior you're seeing; the documentation isn't clear, but I'd expect it to throw an error if you called a disabled function, nor does it explain why `ini_get` returns what you've previously set. It's also entirely possible they're running their own patched version of PHP that alters this behavior. Not unheard of, but unlikely.

Things to try:

- setting it with [session_set_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) instead (needs to be before `session_start`)
- double checking that you're setting the correct param ([`session.cookie_lifetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)) and that your ini_set is definitely placed before session_start, or that you don't have another session_start somewhere else

Comment: Yes I have done both of these. They must be disabling them then. Which is a little annoying when using sessions for user logins. Ill have a chat with them tommrow about it :)

Answer (score -1):

The awser is yes.

The php agent has 3 scopes.

> **1 System**
>
> This one effects all applications. Its the global.ini file. They can
>   also disabling overwrites.
>
> **2 Perdir**
>
> This is your php.ini file. It only effects your directories. Here can
>   you disable overwrites for the script scope and make overwrites in the
>   system scope when allowed
>
> **3 Script**
>
> This is the `ini_set` scope. It can overwrite the perdir & system
>   scope when allowed

***So is it possible for a host to lock out editing of the ini settings?***

Yes they can disable overwrites in there system scope.

Comment: Really? Do you have a source? From what [the documentation says](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), it looks to me like these are baked in to PHP and can't be altered without patching PHP itself. So, if a property is marked as changeable by `PHP_INI_ALL`, I don't see how you can alter it as changeable by `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` instead.